# Parsing a $_POST formatted as an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, post

I receive a funnily formatted $_POST submission in a php script being sent in the form:

```
{"receipt-data":"MILGDgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoILF..."}
```

If I print the $_POST variable I get an Array(), sometimes empty sometimes containing a dictionary "receipt-data":"...." (I was not yet able to understand why sometimes it is empty and sometimes not).
Before it started to arrive empty, I tried to print the first element, but got nothing interesting.

Briefly, what is the correct way to intercept such a posting and get the value corresponding to receipt-data?

This the (quite long) Post data of which I took off some chunks in order to remain in the maximum message allowance:

> Array
>   (
>       [{"receipt-data":"MILOdwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoILOaDCCzmQCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIK_KAYJKoZIhvcNAQcBoIK_GQSCvhUxgr4RMAoCAQgCAQEEAhYAMAoCARQCAQEEAgwAMAsCAQECAQEEAwIBADALAgEDAgEBBAMMATgwCwIBCwIBAQQDAgEAMAsCAQ4CAQEEAwIBGzALAgEPAgEBBAMCAQAwCwIBEAIBAQQDAgEAMAsCARkCAQEEAwIBAzAMAgEKAgEBBAQWAjQrMA0CAQ0CAQEEBQIDARHWMA0CARMCAQEEBQwDMS4wMA4CAQkCAQEEBgIEUDIzMTAYAgEEAgECBBB/lJHT84oy2t4czXgoc79YMBsCAQACAQEEEwwR
>   [...]
>   Ugb2YgdGhlIHRoZW4gYXBwbGljYWJsZSBzdGFuZGFyZCB0ZXJtcyBhbmQgY29uZGl0aW9ucyBvZiB1c2UsIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIHBvbGljeSBhbmQgY2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBwcmFjdGljZSBzdGF0ZW1lbnRzLjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAXDaZTC14t_2Mm9zzd5vydtJ3ME\/BH4WDhRuZPUc38qmbQI4s1LGQEti_9HOb7tJkD8t5TzTYoj75eP9ryAfsfTmDi1Mg0zjEsb_aTwpr\/yv8WacFCXwXQFYRHnTTt4sjO0ej1W8k4uvRt3DfD0XhJ8rxbXjt57UXF6jcfiI1yiXV2Q\/Wa9SiJCMR96Gsj3OBYMYbWwkvkrL4REjwYDieFfU9JmcgijNq9w2Cz97roy\/5U2pbZMBjM3f3OgcsVuvaDyEO2rpzGU_12TZ\/wYdV2aeZuTJC_9jVcZ5_oVK3G72TQiQSKscPHbZNnF5jyEuAF1CqitXa5PzQCQc3sHV1ITGCAcswggHHAgEBMIGjMIGWMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECgwKQXBwbGUgSW5jLjEsMCoGA1UECwwjQXBwbGUgV29ybGR3aWRlIERldmVsb3BlciBSZWxhdGlvbnMxRDBCBgNVBAMMO0FwcGxlIFdvcmxkd2lkZSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgUmVsYXRpb25zIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5AggYWUMhcnSc\/DAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIIBADAfG0M5Lzrl9bhrTKD9nR18Q8HO6zC6XaGtCYtf8a7cE8voswN59EkVCr0yMpcwYxmRjTllJBxJwbPKx3u81B7shTzN5xYfe26nuKqDZBZDo7FqWZSDOhcZ\/E6TEylmWg6kHmWXZJuebDFnLKhQwsgl3H\/atOW4eywXAij_OvPBwPiPc9IBgq4u35oqQL5d2YV38ukBi\/ToqT97\/WG5qvb1JsUDdFoqRuJyA4CCaa8dBlZGDJar29_CjsniFJDz9\/NtUcepZTy3T78POFe2cr_Enrl8E9drcrS4xe5Um9R_CVDNwCgoD1bwYA7M5CjrzNO1dqiXLE59d1i3hgSMS4UxnGLGlXFmlF7DZsjwZil7Eec3XtIaJUlLgnkipOuVUqD1nYw6oBAkCursLDC9AlroN5kWMcEXQXRUgRCItvntJoN897cJX6uXpaaSbiDgXbrwTqnM3/tzHjJgI5T68eI5Dp0LDdxT5FcSd_y3sePf4eTNrJN/eQDMb44ytDg7GOIsG/qiPyHzunp2FrTZZWBIdDP1MvFmLsRoDqvutNqmX5lw3Hobghzk] => "}
>   )

Upon parsing it with:

```
$json=json_encode($_POST);
$data=json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

$data takes the form:

> {"{\"receipt-data\":\"MILP9wYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoILP6DCCz_QCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIK\/qAYJKoZIhvcNAQcBoIK\/mQSCv5Uxgr_RMAoCAQgCAQEEAhYAMAoCARQCAQEEAgwAMAsCAQECAQEEAwIBADALAgEDAgEBBAMMATgwCwIBCwIBAQQDAgEAMAsCAQ4CAQEEAwIBGzALAgEPAgEBBAMCAQAwCwIBEAIBAQQDAgEAMAsCARkCAQEEAwIBAzAMAgEKAgEBBAQWAjQrMA0CAQ0CAQEEBQIDARHWMA0CARMCAQEEBQwDMS4wMA4CAQkCAQEEBgIEUDIzMTAYAgEEAgECBBB5fbMSc4WXteSuDDZ20X4pMBsCAQACAQEEEwwRUHJvZHVjdGlvblNhbmRib3gwHAIBBQIBAQQU6dWy7_Sty19JvZ97C3lbZ7GoJG4wHgIBDAIBAQQWFhQyMDE1LTAxLTAxVDIwOjU4OjUxWjAeAgESAgEBBB
>   [...]
>   b24gQXV0aG9yaXR5AggYWUMhcnSc\/DAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIIBABjGnbWvGn1GhGrK99iWdL_fezRcgTN961IxTFvxt0Ob69SEgVgM\/99DbAOdE5xmVNkXucdNXY6RakQ\/CgoD1bwYA7M5CjrzNO1dqiXLE59d1i3hgSMS4UxnGLGlXFmlF7DZsjwZil7Eec3XtIaJUlLgnkipOuVUqD1nYw6oBAkCursLDC9AlroN5kWMcEXQXRUgRCItvntJoN897cJX6uXpaaSbiDgXbrwTqnM3\/tzHjJgI5T68eI5Dp0LDdxT5FcSd_y3sePf4eTNrJN\/eQDMb44ytDg7GOIsG\/qiPyHzunp2FrTZZWBIdDP1MvFmLsRoDqvutNqmX5lw3Hobghzk":"\"}"}

It is the result of executing the objective-c code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
                                  @"receipt-data": [self.receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
                                  };
     NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
       [...]
```

Comment: Could you print and show us the entire $_POST data?

Comment: Yes, I entered it in the original post as it was quite long.

Comment: Just decode the first  element

Comment: How to decode it? I tried $_POST[0] but got ugly results.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code that creates the request we can see that it is sending the data formatted as JSON, so you will first want to run it through json_decode, e.g.

```
$data=json_decode($_POST[0], TRUE);
```

You don't need to run it through json_encode first as it has already been sent to you as JSON.

Then for the "receipt-data" value itself, we can see that the objective-c code encodes it as base64, so you need to decode it using [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php):

```
$data['receipt-data'] = base64_decode($data['receipt-data']);
```

Comment: I tried that, but now it reverted to receiving an empty array in the $_POST variable:
responseString=Array
(
)
What might be the reason of this random behavior? Of course the parameter starts fine in the url request, I logged it for good measure.

Comment: Ok, this time the receipt got through: yet the error message is: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/iPhone/inarrivo/php/inapp/validateClass.php on line 64, namely in $data=json_decode($_POST[0], TRUE); as I already experimented.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't need the [0], have you tried `$data = json_decode($_POST, TRUE)`?

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/iPhone/inarrivo/php/inapp/validateClass.php on line 64 ; tried again, that was one of my first tests.

Comment: We know the $_POST data is an array, and we know it doesn't like index 0.  I still don't understand exactly how that $_POST array is formatted, but you could do a foreach loop and call json_decode on each value.  You could also print out the indexes and values (in the foreach loop) until you figure out how to access the receipt-data value.  Once you have that value, you will need to base64 decode it.

Comment: I also tried that. The problem is that already the first value is unaccessible, so it has no sense to browse the other ones - also given there is only a single member in the array.

Comment: I also tried that. The problem is that already the first value is unaccessible, so it has no sense to browse the other ones - also given there is only a single member in the array.
The problem seem an unsurmountable one; it seems no one in the internet has found a solution - you may check too. For the time being I have retuned to the old good deprecated transactionReceipt, hoping eventually Apple will make up its mind and provide a solution for that.

Comment: I wouldn't give up just yet.  Can you print out the entire $_POST array that you receive, and copy and paste it to an online service like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?  I will see if I can make sense of it.  Have you confirmed that magic quotes is not turned on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68127/discussion-between-phansen-and-fabrizio-bartolomucci).

Comment: For the time being I restord the transactionreceipt as I need to submit the updated in certain times; at any rate the $_POST array was already submitted in the initial post, only trimming some internal parts of it to fit into the limits of SO. Yet, given we were not able to even extract the value, there could be Goofy or Donald Duck instead of the receipt, and we would have add the same situation.